# Function to add 1 day to date using php

Tags: php

I have tring that contain date

i.e: 2018-07-18

Is there any function that get the string and add 1 day, so the result should be: 2018-07-19

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
$date = "2018-07-18";
$new_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date. ' + 1 days'));
```